# Calculate $f_y(y)$ for all $0 < y < 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I got a probability function $f_{XY}(x,y)$ and we say that $f_y$ is the density function for $Y$, and I don't have this density function, but I have to calculate $f_Y(y)$ for all $0 < y < 1$, how do I then do that?

I have calculated $f_Y(y)$ as the integral ($0$ bottom limit, $1$ upper limit) of $f_{XY}(x,y) dx$.

Then I have used $f_Y(y)$ to try to calculate some examples for $Y$, for example $f_Y(0.1)$, $f_Y(0.5)$ and so forth. But how do I find out what it is exactly for all $0 < y < 1$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just calcuate $f_Y(y)$ by integratinng over $x$ between appropriate limits.But as far as your putting values in a pdf are concered they don't actually give you probabilities,it just gives you the density of the function at that point.
Now to the last part of your question.if you want to get the probability just integrate your between $0$ and $1$.
NOTE: the probability at a point for a continuous random variable is $0$

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate

$$f_Y(y) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\:dx = \int_{a}^{b} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \:dx$$

where $a$ and $b$ are the integration limits for $x$; not the limits for $y$.

Then you have

$$P(0 < Y < 1) =\int_{0}^{1} f_{Y}(y)\:dy$$